# Drag and drop - bubbling or delegation? Tradeoffs

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

Just wanted to understand the tradeoffs of the following two approaches towards implementing drag and drop with vanilla JS

1. apply listeners to the document.body level
2. apply listeners to the specific class itself

JSfiddle here

Overall approach includes

```
var activeDraggedElement; //ADE
var ADE_X, var ADE_Y, var ADE_offsetX, var ADE_offsetY
var startX, startY

function onMouseDown(){}
function onMouseUp(){}
function onMouseMove(){}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/46m5uxod/

I understand that having listeners will be cheaper since we're attaching less listeners to the DOM, but that also means the event will fire many times unnecessarily (the user clicks on a div outside the draggable range).

Thoughts? Is there a better way?

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Just want to understand the tradeoffs between either of the two approaches

Answer (score 0):

Well if we are talking pure "drag and drop" then we are talking about already existing elements.

if we would like to extend the answer we are getting into having a list of elements which might change which in this case i think delegated events are your friend (if considering that the list exists already and is not dynamically loaded into the page.)

In your case i would have passed a rootElement which is as close as possible to the list you are trying to sort (a list container div maybe?) and instead run the lookup on that and limit the amount of "false positives"

```
var onmousedown, onMouseUp;

    onmousedown = function(){...}
    onMouseUp= function(){...}

    function InitDragDrop(rootElement){
      Array.from(rootElement.getElementsByClassName('draggable')
           .forEach(item => {
                    item.addEventListener('onmousedown', onMouseDown)
              item.addEventListener('onmouseup', onMouseUp)     
           });
           )
    }
```